# Update to the newest SDK Admob

Tags: android, jar, sdk, admob, ads

I have bought an android source code that includes Admob ads yet the ads does not show up so i asked the source code publisher it appears that it is using some old Admob SDK or something. The developer wants me to pay more so that he updates the source code. And that is not fair :/. Would you please help me learning to do it myself. I looked into the libs the source code is using GoogleAdmMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar. So how do i update to latests Admob SDK so that the ads show up.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the code.
Start with the Admob developer resources.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: Ok thanks i will have a look. Do i also have to delete the old AdmobSdk jar file and the code used for old admob?

Comment: Hello again William, After applying the tutorial i end up having the following error while exporting my apk : conversion to dalbik format failed with error 1.
Thx a lot for you help

Comment: Try starting with a clean build.

Comment: I tried using Eclipse now i'll try with a clean build using AndroidStudio and get back to you. thx

Comment: Here is what i did :
Using Eclipse (Since Android Studio is really not my thing)
1- I added the code for new banner (link you gave me) I tried the game was still working yet no Ads
2- I then replaced the old google-play-services_lib by the new one and compiled. 
The games crashes when a launch it. 'Stopped working'
I am stuck here plz help ^^

Comment: 'Stopped working' is not sufficient information. What does your logcat say?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but i found the answer. What should be done is deleting the old SDK and every single code integrated in the java of that old Admob and then integrate the new sdk and code :)